# Windows 10 can't find 2nd hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, sata

In my desktop machine there are two disk, an SSD and a 1 GB SATA hard disk. Everything worked fine on Windows 8.1. Then I've installed Windows 10 successfully with the hard disk unplugged. After plugging it in again, it shows up in the BIOS, but not in Windows 10 - neither in the Device Manager nor in Disk Management.

How to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve tried a couple of hints, but the only one that worked was following:

- open the Device Manager,
- right-click the *SATA AHCI Controller* in the *IDE ATA/ATAPI* section
- select *Uninstall* from the context menu
- after reboot the hard disk showed up